# prevent onclick event while changing radio button of primeng

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, primeng

Hi have simple radio buttons of primeng, while changing the choise, I have some logic on the onClick function, checking if the user changed some fields, if he changed I will show message if he sure he want to leave the choice of the radio button, if he will press "cancel" I want to cancel all the event of the onlick function and to undo to his last choise. but the event of the onclick not doing it, I checked all the function of java script. I tried now to add HostListener that if some boolean field(the one that said the user want to undo)it will stopImmediatePropagation. but on runtime the onclick function called and not the HostListener. some ideas what to do?

radio button

```
<p-radioButton name="treesDetailsType"  [(ngModel)]="selectedType" formControlName="selectedType" (onClick)="onChangeType(type,$event)" class="treeDetails" value="{{type.id}}" label="{{type.desc}}" [disabled]="isReadOnly && type.id != data.selectedType"></p-radioButton>
```

the onclick function

```
 onChangeType(type, event) {
    let change = this.checkChanges(type, event);

  
    if (change) {
//HERE I WANT TO CANCEL ALL THE CHANGE AND TO LEAVE THE FUNCTION
      this.clickDisallowed = true;
    }
    else {
      switch (type.id)
..... 
      }
}
```

the host listner

```
  @HostListener('click', ['$event']) onClick(event) {
    if (this.clickDisallowed) {
      event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are using the hostlistener wrongly.
In the angular example it is used inside a directive

https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener
Try this example!

```
@Directive({selector: 'button[counting]'})
class CountClicks {
  numberOfClicks = 0;

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn) {
    console.log('button', btn, 'number of clicks:', this.numberOfClicks++);
 }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  template: '<button counting>Increment</button>',
})
class App {}
```

Comment: thanks but I'm not sure that this is what I need in this case, because I need that after doing some logic in the onclick function the hostlisner (or some other solution) will listen to my boolean field, and it it (this.clickDisallowed) it will       event.stopImmediatePropagation();